# Visual Studio Code custom indentation style

Tags: visual-studio-code

For whatever reason (I hate it, but it is what it is), my company's standard style is to have braces indented to the same level as the code they contain, like this:

```
public static string StringName
    {
    get
        {
        return "string value";
        }
    }
```

This is really easy to set up in Visual Studio (Options > Text Editor > C# (or whatever language) > Code Style > Formatting > Indentation > Indent open and close braces), but I'm unsure how to automate this style in Code. Except for languages like Python where indentation is standardized, this is true of all languages I work in.

How can I accomplish this in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: I didn't. I gave up, and so did my company on getting us to use this wonky style, so it stopped being an issue.

Comment: Well, it's one thing that somebody's used to a style cause that's what s/he was repeatedly shown and it's another thing that somebody uses a style as it's the most logical and neat but unfortunately software developing is not always logical.   Check this out: http://www.activeclickweb.com/whitesmiths/index.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want Whitesmiths style and you're using C# by Omnisharp:
If there is not already such a file, create it: `omnisharp.json`
- in the root of your project if you want the format just for the particular project or
- at `<userdata>/.omnisharp` to use it globally.
Inside it put:

```
{  
"FormattingOptions":  
  {  
  "IndentBraces": true,  
  }  
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/SchemaStore/schemastore/blob/master/src/schemas/json/omnisharp.json) you can find the complete list of formatting options.