# Whitesmiths style in VS Code (C language)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, indentation

I just started using Visual Studio Code. In my company they use Whitesmiths indentation style, but I cannot find a way to set it on VSC.
I'm programming in C, so I installed the C/C++ plugin. In this, the "Indent: Braces" option looks like the one for me, but it does not seem to work.

My json looks like this:

```
"C_Cpp.vcFormat.indent.braces": true,
"editor.detectIndentation": false,
"editor.tabSize": 3,
```

i set detect.Indentation to false, because i don't want it to interfere with indent.braces.
This is the user json. I did not modify the workspace nor the folder settings.

However, my code still looks like this

```
void main()
{
   if(condition)
   {
      do something
   }
   else
   {
      whatever
   }
}
```

while it should look like this

```
void main()
   {
   if(condition)
      {
      do something
      }
   else
      {
      whatever
      }
   }
```

what am I missing? Is there a way to set this from the VSC settings without using the plugin?

Comment: I have seen a lot of styles but this is one of the ugliest I have seen, apart from the one where each function argument is on a separate line

Comment: you can setup your document formatter (prettier) to try to use this style and use `Format Document` on save

Comment: How does the company autoindent the style? If they're going to do style enforcement, they need [to provide] a program to do reindent. There's probably a VS hook that can invoke it. PS. I agree with rioV8. This is the _ugliest_ style I've ever seen [in 40+ years]. It is _so_ bad that, personally, I would refuse to use it. Because I _know_ that it would impede my progress and my code would be more buggy when using it.

Comment: there's no accounting for taste. I personally this is the only logical style around for C++ code..

Answer (score 3):

PFE32 is an ancient editor that will indent in that style. The much newer Code::Blocks editor will handle it as well. Use Astyle to reformat to that style.

By the way, this is the style used with the original Whitesmith's tool chain. It was the first commercially available C compiler. This is the style that God uses when he writes in C. It is not ugly. It is correct, proper for the Backus-Naur  definition of the language. It is pretty, just like me. ;-D

Comment: *This is the style that God uses when he writes in C*  I guess God never had complex `if` conditions that took more than one line?  I find one advantage of the ANSI style is that by putting the opening brace on its own line, aligned vertically with the `if`, finding the break between a multi-line `if` condition and dependent compound statement is easy.

Comment: Not my downvote.  I suspect someone didn't appreciate your tongue-in-cheek endorsement of the Whitesmith code style.

Answer (score 0):

this post is for c# but it worked for me using the visual studio c++ formatter:

[Visual Studio Code custom indentation style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47872149/visual-studio-code-custom-indentation-style)

my full .json file:

```
{
    "[c]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-vscode.cpptools"
    },
    "editor.autoClosingQuotes": "never",
    "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "never",
    "workbench.list.automaticKeyboardNavigation": false,
    "workbench.settings.openDefaultKeybindings": true,
    "update.enableWindowsBackgroundUpdates": false,
    "update.mode": "manual",
    "C_Cpp.formatting": "vcFormat",
    "C_Cpp.vcFormat.indent.braces": true
}
```

Update:

This no longer seems to work as of version 1.82, in particular  "C_Cpp.vcFormat.indent.braces": does not seem to have any impact anymore. And looking at the generic formatter spec (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide) there doesn't seem to be any way to have the indentation occur at the brace, only on the line after it.

Thus the best option now is

```
"editor.autoIndent": "keep"
```

which more or less leaves you responsible for doing your own indentation, but at least prevents the editor from adding unwanted indents.

Comment: Hi Al Ro, i already saw the therad you linked but i don't understand what it means with Omnisharp. Anyway, i copied your entire json but it still does not work...i copied it to AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json, which in my understanding is the json that is applied to every project on my machine...should i copy it to a different one?

Comment: use the menu options inside vscode to open your settings json, that's the safest way.

Comment: "C_Cpp.vcFormat.indent.braces": true doesn't seem to do anything anymore, seems like maybe a code regression.